# using SSE to send image data

Tags: html, server, server-sent-events

All examples that I have seen that implement server sent events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) set content type of the response to `text/event-stream`.

I was hoping to send image data using the SSE mechanism. But I am not sure if this will work with a text content type.

Can I use SSE for this? Or do I need a "full scale" connection for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could*, by base64-encoding the image (SSE does not support sending binary). But (looking at your comment on the other answer that these are large images), don't do that. Assuming the current image generation is timing out because it is slow to generate, not huge, here is how I would do it:

1. Call /make_my_image/
2. This is an SSE process, that starts making the image. It sends the usual header.
3. When the image is ready, save it to local disk (or in an in-memory database, etc.)
4. Use SSE to send back the URL where the image can be downloaded. Then close the SSE process (server-side).
5. Client requests the image through Apache (or whatever).
6. Client could send a message to say when it is has got the image and it can be deleted. And/or use a cron job to clear away old images after so many hours.

I.e. this plays to SSEs advantage of being good for low-latency text messages: as soon as the image is made the client can download it. Much better than a background process making the image, and then the client has to poll to find out when it is ready.

If privacy is important - no-one else should be able to download an image - then step 5 could be a PHP (or language of your choice) script that checks the client cookie matches your session, and only streams the file through if so.

Answer (score 0):

For really big images, I would at least stream via [web sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). However, getting the server side (and backend) might be tricky.

Alternatively, you could tile the image and use simple HTTP requests. There are plenty of approaches and libraries, one of them would be using Leaflet. 
Here is a decent explanation: http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/

All you need to do is to split your huge image into tiles, then you can even put it on the static server. Tiles have to follow convention `[zoom_level]/map_[0..NX]_[0..NY].png`

Then you set a coordinate reference system (CRS) to `L.CRS.Simple` and make the tile layer work with your image server:

`L.tileLayer('/image1234/tiles/{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png').addTo(map);`

Server-sent events should really be used as unsolicited notification mechanism if something of importance happens on the server and browser client needs to be aware of it. E.g. another answer has been posted to SO question, while you are editing. The actual data is always retrieved via extra request.

Web sockets are good for anything full duplex TCP sockets are good for (i.e. pretty much everything). But it is fairly low level - even though for specific applications there are some open source aids. If large image rendering is the focus and selling point of your application, it might make sense to invest into it.

Fast to production, robust and relatively low cost solution to solve your problem (showing huge image) would be image tiling, though.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pack-bytes-to-utf8

server

```
import { uint8ArrayToUtf8 } from 'pack-bytes-to-utf8'

const excludeCharacters = new Set([0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE])
const binary = new Uint8Array([0xff, 0xff, 0xff])

...

res.send(`data: ${uint8ArrayToUtf8(binary, excludeCharacters)}`)
```

client

```
import { utf8ToUint8Array } from 'pack-bytes-to-utf8'

...

eventSource.on('message', (event) => {
    console.log(utf8ToUint8Array(event.data))
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.